# DateTime Null Variable Format

Tags: c#, .net

I have a variable that receives DATETIME type ,And sometimes comes from DB NULL variable  So I have this code .

```
DateTime? d;
DateTime dtq; 
don.Date_appeal_donor= d = DateTime.TryParse(dr["Date_"].ToString(), out dtq) ? dtq : (DateTime?)null;
```

And I can not change the format to "dd / MM / yyyy" Does anyone have a solution?

You're right, now I realized that only when it comes to DATAGRIDVIEW It changes the display This is in wpf. So I fill the data grid

```
  dataGrid1.ItemsSource= DAL.LoadCollectionData();
```

And here I am stuck

Comment: I assume that `dr["Date_"]` actually already is a `DateTime` variable, why do you convert it then first to a `String` and then try-parse it back to a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` like this:

```
DateTime dtq;
DateTime? d;

don.Date_appeal_donor = d = DateTime.TryParseExact(dr["Date_"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date) ? dtq : (DateTime?)null;
```